# How to downgrade python version on CentOS?

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, sha

I have a dedicated web server which runs CentOS 6.6

I am running some script that uses Python SHA module and I think that this module is deprecated in the current Python version.

I am consider downgrading my Python installation so that I can use this module.

Is there a better option? If not, how should I do it?

These are my Python installation details:

```
rpm-python-4.8.0-38.el6_6.x86_64
dbus-python-0.83.0-6.1.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-canvas-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
libreport-python-2.0.9-21.el6.centos.x86_64
gnome-python2-applet-2.28.0-5.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-gconf-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-bonobo-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-9.el6.noarch
python-tools-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
newt-python-0.52.11-3.el6.x86_64
python-ethtool-0.6-5.el6.x86_64
python-pycurl-7.19.0-8.el6.x86_64
python-docs-2.6.6-2.el6.noarch
gnome-python2-libegg-2.25.3-20.el6.x86_64
python-iwlib-0.1-1.2.el6.x86_64
libxml2-python-2.7.6-17.el6_6.1.x86_64
gnome-python2-gnome-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch
gnome-python2-libwnck-2.28.0-5.el6.x86_64
libproxy-python-0.3.0-10.el6.x86_64
python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-gnomevfs-2.28.0-3.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-desktop-2.28.0-5.el6.x86_64
gnome-python2-extras-2.25.3-20.el6.x86_64
abrt-addon-python-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64
at-spi-python-1.28.1-2.el6.centos.x86_64
python-libs-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
python-devel-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: I would be very wary downgrading your default python

Comment: i think itis not the default as it was working good but after updating yum this problem proceeds

Comment: You can install another version of python using `make altinstall` http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/ If you screw with the default you will break your OS

Comment: And create a virtual environment that suits your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always install a different version of Python using the -altinstall argument, and then run it either in a virtual environment, or just run the commands with python(version) command.

A considerable amount of CentOS is written in Python so changing the core version will most likely break some functions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of literally downgrading, I would consider [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).  It lets you create isolated python environments, including the specific python version and the modules.