# Uninstall python 2.6 without yum

Tags: python, linux, centos, yum, system-configuration

I accidentally downloaded python2.6.6 on my centos Virtual Machine from python.org's official download package and compiled it to source.

Now in my /usr/local/bin I have a python2.6 shell available and now if I use `which python` it will give me the path of /usr/local/bin instead of original python2.7's path which is /usr/bin.

Since I installed it from source, yum doesn't recognise python2.6.6 as a package and I want to get rid of it.

If I do `rpm -q python` it gives me a result of python-2.7.5-48.0.1.el7.x86_64

Is it possible to uninstall python2.6.6 and I will just re-point my python system variable to /usr/bin again?

Comment: Accidentaly downloaded and compiled sounds strange hehe, one question, did you installed a rpm right?

Comment: Did you checked if the compilation allows a 'make unistall'? as you did a make install

Comment: yes I did not "accidentaly" downloaded and compiled the package, I have a old Django project that depends on python2.6.6 but centos 7 depends on python2.7 now, so my new working environment does not have python2.6 installed, also yum does not have python2.6 on its repository, that's why I compiled it from source.

Comment: Ok, so, take a look to this post hope will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235059/how-to-downgrade-python-version-on-centos

Comment: once I have downloaded the Python-2.6.6.tgz and unzipped it, I am able to run python2.6.6 from the unzipped file, does that mean I don't actually have to do the ./configure.py and make build process to compile it to source code? I do have a virtualenv environment available, should I just configure virtualenv to use uncompiled version of the python2.6.6?

Comment: the reason I want get rid of this compiled python2.6.6 version: 1.I got couple warnings and configuration erros when I compiled it, I don't want run into any trouble if I'm gona use this version in the future for a long time 2.I recently learned its not a good practice to install anything from source without using yum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157314/discussion-between-kalamarico-and-paradox).

Comment: @paradox Is the version of `python` you want to remove installed as an rpm? Could you please do `rpm -q python` and edit your question, or post a reply.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you'll have to do it the hard way. Dig through `/usr/local` looking for anything Python-related and remove it. The `python` in `/usr/bin` should be revealed once the one in `/usr/local/bin` is removed.

Also, next time `make altinstall`. It will install a versioned executable that won't get in the way of the native executable.

Comment: that's what I did to my /usr/local, I'm worried the system environment variable will cause a problem if I don't get rid of the python-->/usr/local/bin/python2.6